# How to programmatically trigger document generation in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to trigger a Document generation programmatically in EA similar to HTML generation?

Is there any way to do like below "**RunHTMLReport**" for document generation?

"**RunHTMLReport(PackageGUID,ExportPath ,ImageFormat,Style,Extension)**"

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas said, you can use `Repository.CreateDocumentGenerator`. However, this is a whole facility for generating a report (the best way to describe it would be like if you are doing virtual documents, but in code).

This is really used to define a report template from model fragments.
[Here's the documentation on using the Document Generator](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/document_generator_interface_class.html)

To run a report on an already defined template, use `Project.RunReport`. [You can find the documentation here.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/project_2.html)

You get your Project object with `Repository.GetProjectInterface`

Comment: Actually your answer is the correct one and I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

RTFM: `Repository.CreateDocumentGenerator` in [EA's documentation](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/document_generator_interface.html)

Comment: there's a good difference between the document generator and the document generation used in the user interface. For the record, Project.RunReport also works. (But if you can go the document generator route, i suggest that)

Comment: @Hue Ah, yes. You should post that as answer.